# Magento 2: how to use $this->_initLayoutMessages('checkout/session')?

Tags: magento2

What does this function do in magento 2?

```
$this->_initLayoutMessages('checkout/session');
return $this;
```

I am new in Magento & I am going to migrating M1-> M2 , So can anyone please let me know how to use **_initLayoutMessages('checkout/session')** in Magento 2?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, this is Magento1 code.

> $this->_initLayoutMessages('checkout/session');

And you can use following code in Magento2 :

```
protected $messageManager;

public function __construct(\Magento\Framework\Message\ManagerInterface $messageManager)
{
     $this->messageManager = $messageManager;
}
```

With this, you can call one of the following messages:

```
$this->messageManager->addSuccess(__("Success"));
$this->messageManager->addError(__("Error"));
$this->messageManager->addWarning(__("Warning"));
$this->messageManager->addNotice(__("Notice"));
```

Comment: Thanks @dhiren , It's works for me :)